# Conjugate of a complex series is series of the conjugates

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

[image]

I am talking about part (i). We know it's convergent so it converges to some $\large z_s \in \mathbb{C}$ , don't know how to show it's equivalent to the series of the conjugates though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove this with the definition of convergence of a series.

Say $\sum_{k=0}^\infty z_k = z$. That means that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is an $N$ such that 
$$ \left| \sum_{k=0}^n z_k - z \right| < \epsilon \; \text{ for all } n \geq N.$$

But then

$$\left| \;  \sum_{k=0}^n \bar{z_k} - \bar{z}  \; \right | =  \left| \; \overline{ \sum_{k=0}^n z_k - z } \; \right | = \left| \sum_{k=0}^n z_k - z \right| < \epsilon \; \text{ for all } n \geq N$$

since conjugation behaves well with absolute values and finite sums.

Comment: it makes sense, however it seems like the problem wants me to show explicitly that the sum of $z_k$ bar is bar of the sum of $z_k$. I'm not sure if what you have is enough.

Comment: how can I do part (ii)?

Comment: I don't know how you would the sums are equal more explicitly - they are infinite, so defining them at all requires this sort of limit. For (ii), you could use a similar argument as the above, or use the fact that $2\text{Re }z = z + \bar{z}$ and $2\text{Im }z = z - \bar{z}$.